# Draw, Move shapes In java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, move, shapes

I am doing a project regarding the movement of shapes drawn in a `JPanel` but if i implement a `mouselistener` to my class how can i do if i have multiple shapes drawn? In my example i have drawn two rectangles.
This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class NewClass1 extends JFrame{
        JPanel panel2;
        
    public NewClass1(){
        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
         panel2 = new jPanel2();

        container.add(panel2);
        
        add(container);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NewClass1();
    }
    
    class jPanel2 extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
        g.drawRect(21, 21, 20, 20);
    }}
}
```

Comment: Keep your shapes in a `List` of some kind, then you do basic hit detection

Answer (score 0):

The `java.awt.Rectangle` class is available to hold logical rectangles.

I reworked your code and made the following changes.

1. I started the Swing application with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
2. I created and added two rectangles to a `List` of `Rectangles`.
3. The `JFrame` methods must be called in a certain order.  This is the order I use for most of my Swing applications.
4. I gave the drawing `JPanel` a preferred size, rather than the `JFrame`.  You want to know how large your drawing area is.  The size of the `JFrame` is irrelevant to drawing.

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
    
    public class ShapesExample extends JFrame {
    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
        private List<Rectangle> rectangles;
    
        public ShapesExample() {
            rectangles = new ArrayList<>();
            rectangles.add(new Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20));
            rectangles.add(new Rectangle(41, 41, 20, 20));
            
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setTitle("Shapes Example");
    
            add(new DrawingPanel());
            
            pack();
            setLocationByPlatform(true);
            setVisible(true);
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new ShapesExample();
                }
            });
        }
    
        class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
    
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            
            public DrawingPanel() {
                this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
            }
    
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
    
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                for (Rectangle rectangle : rectangles) {
                    g.drawRect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, 
                            rectangle.width, rectangle.height);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```